# Проверка доступа к статическим файлам в NodeJS

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, express, веб-сервер, static

У меня есть файлы которые загружают пользователи на сервер (NodeJS).
Сейчас доступ к этим файлам можно получить через статику.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static', 'images')))
```

Но таким образом любой пользователь может получить к ним доступ, если у него есть ссылка.
Как мне добавить проверку на то, что файл хочет получить именно его владелец?
Своего рода middleware для static.
Спасибо!

Comment: Я вижу 2 вариант реализации: 1. Создать таблицу соответствия пользовать - файл. 2. Разложить файлы в папки с именами пользователей и сверять имя пользователя с запрошенной папкой

Comment: Ну так а какая проблема написать миддлварь?

Comment: Таблица уже есть. Мне необходимо узнать, как реализовать этот middleware, где будет сравниваться пользователь (Через bearer token) и доступ к файлу.